# Jquery vs Javascript setting an html hidden boolean field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

Why does this JQuery version Not work and the JavaScript one does?  I prefer to use JQuery.  Any answers much appreciated!

Razor Hidden boolean field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.is_valid_number, new { @id = "is_valid_number"
   });
```

JQuery (This Don't Work)

```
$("is_valid_number").val("True");
```

JavaScript (This Works)

```
document.getElementById('is_valid_number').value = "True";
```

Answer (score 2):

getElementById in jQuery must use "#" like this

```
$("#is_valid_number").val("True");
```

Comment: Oh man... I did see that missing "#" shortly after posting this.  The little things after putting in a 12+ hour day already.  Sorry if this was redundant or what not. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The selector of element selected by `document.getElementById("xyz")` function, becomes `#xyz`. So try with `$("#is_valid_number").val("True");` and it should work.

I would **strongly** suggest reading up on CSS selectors to get better idea of how they work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Yes, thank you @Nisarg Shah, appreciate the quick responses.  I was trying to find an Undo option on this site right when I seen the missing "#" LOL

Answer (score 1):

As **is_Valid_number** is an id, you should use this

```
$("#is_valid_number").val("True");
```

Answer (score 0):

for id you have to use **#** befor it, and for Class use **.(dot)**

$("#is_valid_number").val("True");